# X509Certificates in UWP

Tags: windows, reference, nuget, x509certificate, uwp

Is it possible to use     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates     in an UWP application? I get a reference error, but can't seem to find any existing library that includes this? Maybe a NuGet package?

Comment: X509Certificates namespace is defined in System.dll library.

Comment: I have referenced the System.dll, so it might not be part of UWP's .NET?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in UWS, but as long it is a .NET, the same libraries are used (I believe).

Comment: Sadly a lot of stuff is not included in the .NET version that UWP uses, but do you know of any other way in which I could do a X509Certificate instead of this unusable library?

Comment: yes, it appears that .NET for UWP is very cut significantly. As an alternative option, you can use Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212099.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use the System.Security.Cryptography in the Universal Windows Platform App. It is included in the full .NET (desktop .NET), and the .NET for UWP does not have it.

As CryptoGuy suggested, you can use the [Certificate class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificate) which is provided by the Windows Runtime Components.

**UPDATE (11/2/2016)**

According to the latest document [.NET for UWP Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185501.aspx), X509Certificates is included in .NET for UWP.